# Why can't I convert the list that I fetched with readlines(), to floats?

Tags: python

I've opened a new file via my IDE and turned it into a list via readlines. Why? Because I want to print them underneath each other. When I use `read()`, it just prints one item, while I need the whole list to be printed.

The actual file:

```
['Some name__________1.5 6.5 6.5\n', 'Another name________6.3 1.2 1.5\n']
```

Right now, I have managed to fetch the last part of the list which looks likes this:

```
1.5 3.5 4.5
2.5 3.5 4.5
5.5 3.5 4.5
```

**What I want to do now, is to calculate the average of these numbers, but: Python does not recognize them as numbers (ints, floats) at all.**

When I'd use `type(TheVariableThatContainsMyList)`, it doesn't show the type of it. Therefore, I don't think they are ints, strings or floats.

What I think I need to do, is to convert the items in this list, into floats, because they are supposed to be floats. But to do so, I need to know what I am doing wrong and how I could fix that.

**This is my code:**

```
def zopenFile():
    fileFolder = open('TEXTFILE', 'r')

    readFile = fileFolder.readlines()

    for line in readFile:
        line = line.split("_")

        grades = line[-1]

        print grades

zopenFile()
```

I tried doing `grades = map(float,line[-1])`

But in that case, the console says: `could not convert string to float: .`

The weird part is, that if I would use `type(grades)`, it wouldn't say it has the type of a string in the console. I am confused right now... is it a string? Is it a float already? If so, why can't I just map it into a float?

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

And I know I can use `read()`, but I don't want to. Can someone show me how to do it with `readlines()` instead?

Comment: Why are you trying to split on underscores when your example data is separated by spaces? Why are you doing `grades = line[-1]`?

Comment: Show us an actual sample of the text file.

Comment: Sorry, I've posted the actual file I am putting in. Will make sense now, I hope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` is operating on each *character* of the string, because when you iterate over a string you get individual characters. You want to use another `split` to get each number into separate strings.

```
grades = map(float, line[-1].split())
```

Comment: Ah, so the list I had with the numbers, was a string in that case? What is the reason it didn't say that when I'd use type()? Thanks for helping by the way, this looks like it's working now!

Comment: @Siyah - you must have made a mistake, it is definitely a string.

Comment: @Siyah your first `split` produced a list of strings, and you were using `[-1]` to get the last string from that list.

Comment: Thank you Mark, but still wondering why type() didn't work in that case... can you explain that too?

Comment: @Siyah `type(line)` is `list`, `type(line[-1])` is `str`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I appreciate it, but why is line[-1] a string? Because everything in a list is a string by default?

Comment: @Siyah `split` produces a list of strings, and you did `line = line.split("_")`. Using a subscript `[-1]` on a list (if you don't use `:` to get slicing) produces a single element of the list, and *each* element of this list is a string. I hope you understand this now, because I don't think I can describe it any more clearly.